# Redisplay edittext with hint

Tags: android, android-edittext, reset

I have an editext field. When the user enters incorrect data , i want to redisplay the hint, or at least the field with underscores. I tried cleartext but that  leaves screen blanck

Comment: You can do `editText.setError("something")`. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an if statement.

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button mButton;
EditText mEditText;
String inputAnswer = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextExample);
    mEditText.setHint("Take a guess!");



    mButton= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTest);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            inputAnswer = mEditText.getText().toString();
            if(inputAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("correct answer")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct answer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else mEditText.setText("");
```

This way if the inputted editText is equal to "correct answer" (which can be changed to whatever you need), it displays a Toast saying correct answer, if not, it clears the text and displays the hint you set (in this case "Take a guess!")